# How to handle a collection of items when passing them to a helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a helper that receives a group of attachments collection and tries to calculate if the images are square or not.

On the views I have a condition like `suggestion_grid_square?(@attachments)` and the helper methods are.

(I have simplified the code to make it clearer for the problem of this question)

```
  def suggestion_grid_square?(*attachments) 
    suggestion_column_squares?(1,attachments)
  end

  def attachment_square?(attachment)
    (attachment.file_height.to_f / attachment.file_width) <= 1
  end

  private

  def suggestion_column_squares?(column,*attachments)
    attachments.each do |attachment|
      attachment_square?(attachment)
    end
  end
```

The following code is returning me this error: `undefined method file_height for #<Array:0x007fa827e9af30>`

`` app/helpers/suggestions_helper.rb:8:in `attachment_square?'
app/helpers/suggestions_helper.rb:15:in `block in suggestion_column_squares?' ``

Any idea why it is not receiving the `file_height` attribute or what Im doing wrong here?

**Update** this is how I create the collection and how I call the helper on views:

```
boutique_products = Product.by_most_recent.sold_or_designed_by(boutique).shuffle.first(4)
boutique_products.each { |product| (@attachments << product.default_attachment_or_first_attachment) } 

.follow-boutique-grid{class: ("square-suggestion-grid" if suggestion_grid_square?(@attachments)) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `suggestion_grid_square?`, attachments is already an array from the splat argument (*attachments). Then you pass it into the `suggestion_column_squares?` which again splats the argument. But since attachments is already an array, the splat will just make an array of the array. So your attachments variable inside of `suggestion_column_squares?` looks like:

```
[[attachment1, attachment2, etc...]]
```

When you call `each`, you are really just looping through the outer element 1 time and passing in an array. This is why you get an error about calling `file_height` on an array, since `attachment` (in the each) is not what you are expecting.

You should remove the splat operator (*) from the attachment parameter from `suggestion_column_squares?`:

```
def suggestion_column_squares?(column, attachments)
  attachments.each do |attachment|
    attachment_square?(attachment)
  end
end
```